# Would the brake proportioning valve be the cause of my brakes getting tight by themselves.

Tags: ford, maintenance, repair, focus

I own a Ford Focus 2006 Zx4 2.0

Well I'm asking if the brake proportioning valve could be the cause of my brakes getting tight on their own. I have asked another mechanic and told me it could be it.

My older mechanic had gave up on me, my brakes would get tight on their own while driving freeway or regular street

Let's say I'm going 30 miles per hour and when I let go of the gas pedal it would automatically slow down quick to 20 or so mph.

With my old mechanic. We changed the master cylinder, brake booster , rotors and calipers. Plus brake hoses.

Details on how it starts to get tight.

1. The car would rumble a little and you'll start feeling the strength of the car slow down because the front right brake will start heating up and getting tight
2. Doesn't matter if it's hot or a cold day.
3. Only temporary solution that I've found is when I turn off the car and release the pressure on my brakes by pressing the breve pedal several times.

*yes I've bled them correctly but my mechanic and also auto zone tech said that this type of Focus has a special way of bleeding starting from the rear passenger and jumping across to the drivers side then passengers and rear driver brake i don't know if it's true or not..  *

> I doubt this is related to the front right brakes getting tight. But a while back my front brakes were tightening up. And while I exited the freeway my rear left drum brake blew out , breaking or ripping the cylinder causing all my brake fluid to leak out and drove with no brakes. But luckily i was slowing down with the 10% brake power I had.
>   Eventually I changed back drum brake parts because the old ones were worn out badly. Hasn't happened to me before. 
>   When the drum break blew out it caused a small flame burning the abs sensor so now my light is on.

*I've had this problem a while and spent lots of money on parts and labor. I'm trying to sell the car but I can't in this condition. *